# MPLAB IDE x 3.55 best way to include files in project

Tags: c, ide, mplab, pic24

I am compiling a project in which I am using USB as a data logger. The host PIC micro is PIC24FJ, however the compiler is always complaining about NO such file or directory. I have tries the following methods to include those files which the compiler should be able find and include.

1: Added under the Header file on left hand side Projects Pane.

2: Added through Project Properties -> General -> Add.

3: Added through Project Properties -> XC-16-gcc -> option categories -> Prepocessign and messages -> c include dirs.

i have used both relative and absolute paths.
SO i am really confused What is the best way of including directories and files in MPLAB IDE x.

Comment: Just include and select the include path in project/properties

Comment: MPLABX 3.55 ist pretty old, Are you sure about the version?

Comment: @Mike. i have done that but still complains about the file or directory not found and yes i am still using 3.55 but going to update to latest version hopefully that would remove this issue.